# Ternary operator and code suggestion needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In JS file `$scope.button = id ? "Edit" : "Add";` is working fine. I want to use it in View like

```
    <button name="saveBtn" class="btn btn-primary" 
tabindex="10">{{person.id ? 'Edit' : 'Add'}}</button>
```

**1 -** Above code is not working. Tried different combinations.

**2 -** Should I use View or Js file to keep this code?

**3 -** [Applying code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588951/few-basic-questions-troubling-me-related-to-angularjs/16589277?noredirect=1#16589277)

**Question is :** I have initialized `init()` function like below. Is it correct approach or you have anything better to share?

```
app.controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, personService) {

    list();
    function list() {
        var id = ($routeParams.id) ? parseInt($routeParams.id) : 0;
        if (id > 0) {
            $scope.person = {};
            $scope.person = personService.getPersonById(id);
        } else
        //$scope.people = [];
        $scope.people = personService.getPeople();
    };

    $scope.edit = function () {

    };

    $scope.delete = function (id) {

    };

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax used inside the handlebars `{{}}` is not full JavaScript, but [Angular expression language](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). The ternary operator is currently not available in this expression language (but it is [coming soon](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b)). For now you can use this syntax instead:

```
{{ person.id && 'Edit' || 'Add' }}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to assign the value and function of your button based on something in the scope?  Why not set a scope.action to Edit or Add and check for it?